# DOM Traversa l Question - Using mutationObserver to insertAdjacentHTML after each node, and to addEventListener to each button

Tags: javascript, nodes, traversal, mutation-observers

So, I'm using setMutationObserver to insertAdjacentHTML input buttons in to a div class named '._5pcq'. after the end of that class. That class is located inside of a container named '._3576'.

> https://greasyfork.org/scripts/12228/code/setMutationHandler.js

Once that's done, I am using the setMutationObserver to addEventListener('click', function(event) {} to each button that has been inserted in to the '._5pcq' class. Which means it's looking inside of each '._3576' class for the buttons after they've been inserted, which means that I'm pointing the second MutationObserver to look for '.TextCopyButton' inside _3576, and for each node(.TextCopyButton) that it finds, it's adding the listener.

Now, in order to copy the text in the '._3576' class. I need to traverse from the event.target which is (.TextCopyButton) up to where the text to be copied is located at. Which is 2 parentNodes up, nextSibling, nextSibling, and then up 9 parentNodes. Without losing track of the current node.

event.target.parentNode.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.nextSibling;

I can not do getElementsByClassName(_3576), because that will require a node index number. Which means I need to use event.target to reference the current node that the button is clicked from. My question is how can I reference the current node, and get to the location I need to without using so many parentNode chains.

I need something along the lines of event.target.parentNode[2].nextSibling[2].parentNode[9]
OR
event.target.traverseToNode('.3576');

I have no idea what else to try. I have tried getElementsByClassName('_3576')[event.target]

I have tried using the THIS keyword.

My code is located here:

```
setMutationHandler({
target: document.querySelector('._3576'),
selector: '.copybtnP',
handler: nodes => nodes.forEach(node => {
    node.setAttribute("style", "color:blue; border: 1px solid blue;");
    node.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        var classCheck = document.getElementsByClassName('canvasArea');
        var status_content = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.nextSibling; 

        if (classCheck.length > 0) {
            status_content = event.target.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling;
        }
                //alert(status_content + ' (Working)');
                //alert(event.target.previousSibling.innerText);
          getSelection().removeAllRanges();
          var range = document.createRange();
          range.selectNode(status_content);
          window.getSelection().addRange(range);







try { var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
//console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
} catch (err) {console.log('Oops, unable to copy');}
          return false;
      })
})

});
```

https://pastebin.com/Et66j0uc

Answer (score 0):

I think you buried your question inside a bunch of unnecessary description. From what I understand, you want to simply reduce the number of `.parentNode` calls when traversing up the DOM.

The most obvious answer is to create a function that takes the starting point and the number of traversals, and does them in a loop.

```
function up(start, num) {
  while (--num >= 0 && (start = start.parentNode)) {
    // nothing to do in the loop body
  }
  return start
}

const res = up(event.target, 2)
```

Then you can do the same for sibling traversal.

However, you can also use the `.closest()` method for going up through the ancestors, assuming you can describe the element targeted with a selector.

```
const res = event.target.closest(".someParentClass")
```

This should prove to be more resilient against changes you make to the DOM, assuming your selector is well defined.

Comment: I tried my best to ask as specific of a question as I could to eliminate any confusion having had trouble with people understanding before. It seems everytime I post on StackOverflow I get downvoted. Thank you though.

Comment: If I understood it, the question was asking how to do this repeated traversal in a more concise way. If so, it's a good idea to focus on that part, and put together an example that fully illustrates it, rather than trying to explain the actual, surrounding code. Anyway, hope it helped.

Comment: I added the extra information because people weren't understanding elsewhere. Oh well.